# Swipe to dismiss Keyboard - Ionic, Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm developing a chat for our app and I was wondering if there was any way to implement swipe to dismiss the keyboard similar to iMessage. When you swipe the area right above the keyboard in a downward motion it closes the keyboard.

I've been googling & not coming up with anything that sounds viable. Wondering if any of you have figured this out.

I attempted adding a div that listens for swipes that is absolutely positioned at the bottom of the screen but then it'll block me from clicking into the text bar / send button.

Any advice is greatly appreciated :)